# How to get and print the image within the page in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to print the image within the page. here is my code

```js
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="radio" value="<img src='images/image1.jpg'>">
    <img src="images/image1.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
    <input type="radio" value="<img src='images/image2.jpg'>">
    <img src="images/image2.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"><br/>
    <input type="radio" value="Both" />Both<br/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#showoption').val(value);
    });
</script>

<label>Value</label>  
<input type="text" id="showoption" name="name" disabled="disabled"> 
</label>
```

When I click on selected radio button the image it prints the image url. how to print the selected image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting exact image tag with src so what you need to do is just put it in some HTML in page. So i change the input box with div and now on click the div will be fill with Image tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input:radio[type=radio]").click(function() {
var value = $(this).val();
$('#showoption').html(value);
    });
</script>

<label>Value</label>

<div id="showoption"></div>
```

Comment: @srikanth Glad I can help

Comment: when i click on radio button image is displayed but when i click on image the image is not displayed

Comment: What do you mean by when you click on Image,If you are able to click on Image that means it is visible to you.

Comment: how to set <div id="showoption"></div> within the image tag.or how to pass this id in image tag.